# Declare variables to DbMigration.CreateStoredProcedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use `DbMigration.CreateStoredProcedure` to create a function that takes an integer `InvoiceId` and returns a decimal. However, when I apply the migration, I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@InvoiceId".

This is the EF migration code:

```
CreateStoredProcedure("SumInvoiceTransactions", b => b.Decimal(9, 2),
    "RETURN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Transactions WHERE InvoiceId=@InvoiceId)");
```

This is the equivalent SQL code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SumInvoiceTransactions(@InvoiceId int) RETURNS decimal
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT sum(Amount) FROM Transactions WHERE InvoiceId=@InvoiceId)
END
```

How do I declare the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
CreateStoredProcedure("SumInvoiceTransactions", c => new { InvoiceId = c.Int() },
"RETURN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Transactions WHERE InvoiceId=@InvoiceId)");
```

Comment: How do I declare the return type? Or do I need to?